# Can't resolve AWS ElastiCache redis cluster endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I'm trying to use an elasticache redis cluster from a fargate service, but am getting address resolution issues - "ENOTFOUND" errors from "getaddrinfo" for the cluster endpoint in my code, and NXDOMAIN errors if I try and do nslookup from inside the container.

The cluster is set up as

```
resource "aws_elasticache_cluster" "redis_service" {
  cluster_id           = "${terraform.workspace}-${local.app_name}-redis-service"
  engine               = "redis"
  node_type            = "cache.t4g.micro"
  num_cache_nodes      = 1
  parameter_group_name = "default.redis6.x"
  engine_version       = "6.2"
  port                 = 6379
  subnet_group_name = aws_elasticache_subnet_group.redis_subnet.name
  security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.redis.id]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "redis" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.ecs-vpc.id
  name   = "${terraform.workspace}-redis"

  ingress {
    from_port       = 0
    to_port         = 0
    protocol        = "-1"
    self            = true
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] # Originally had this restricting to the security group that my fargate service is in, but made it less restrictive trying to debug the issue
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

### AZ 1 (and similar for other AZs)
resource "aws_subnet" "redis1" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.ecs-vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.40.0/24"
  availability_zone = "eu-west-2a"
}

resource "aws_route_table" "redis1" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.ecs-vpc.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "redis1" {
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.redis1.id
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.redis1.id
}

resource "aws_route" "redis1" {
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  nat_gateway_id         = aws_nat_gateway.subnet1.id
  route_table_id         = aws_route_table.redis1.id
}
```

The fargate service I'm trying to connect from is in the same vpc.

I've checked throw the AWS documentation on connected to elasticache clusters, but not seen anything that seems to be missing.

The VPC reachability analyzer seems to confirm that the cluster should be reachable from the service (using the relevant enis).

Any ideas for fixes or debugging steps?

Comment: Check that you have `DNS Support` and `DNS Hostnames` both enabled on your VPC https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html

Comment: Hasn't changed anything sadly - both are enabled, errors are the same (previously they were the defaults, which had only one of those enabled).

Comment: Have you tried resolving that address from an EC2 instance in the same subnet you are trying to deploy the Fargate service to?

Comment: I've tried using ecs exec to run a shell command inside the running docker container for my service, which couldn't resolve the address...

Comment: @meta Hello, I've faced exactly the same issue. How did you overcome it?